# Extract precipitation values for polygons over PRISM dataset using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, precipitation

I am trying to extract monthly PRISM ppt values over 58 polygons for 1 year. I am able to extract the values for one month (image), but when I try to map over the entire image collection, the result has zero columns. Code is adapted from a previous post on a similar issue ([Daily Rainfall data extraction from CHIRPS database for polygons using Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408555/daily-rainfall-data-extraction-from-chirps-database-for-polygons-using-google-ea/408570#408570)). When I run the code from the previous post I also receive an output with zero columns. Any ideas what is driving this error?

```
var imgcol = ee.ImageCollection('OREGONSTATE/PRISM/AN81m'),
    catchm = ee.FeatureCollection("users/Ctester14/all_catchments")


//Set Time Period
var img_col = imgcol.filter(ee.Filter.date ('2012-01-01', '2012-12-30'));
var image = img_col.first()

//deriving the date of the image
var date= image.get('system:index')

//zonal statistics
var mean_rain = function (feature){
  var rain = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: feature.geometry(),
    scale: 4000, //the PRISM dataset has 4K degree resolution
  });
  var sdis_rain = feature.set('Mean Rainfall', rain.get('ppt'))
  .set ("Date", date);
  return sdis_rain;
};

//running the function for all features in the shapefile
var rainfall = catchm.map(mean_rain);
print (rainfall);
/*
 Export.table.toDrive ({
  collection: rainfall,
  description: 'Mean Rain',
  selectors: ['Dscrptn', 'Date', 'Mean Rainfall']
  })
*/


// Run across all dates as well as features
var totalOutput = ee.ImageCollection(img_col).map(function(image){
  //deriving the date of the image
  var date= image.get('system:index')
  
  var test = catchm.map(function(feature){ 
    var rain = image.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: feature.geometry(),
      scale: 4000,
    });
    
   return ee.Feature(feature.set('MeanRain', rain.get('ppt'))
                            .set ("Date", date))
  })
  
  return ee.FeatureCollection(test);
}).flatten()

print(totalOutput.limit(10))
```

Comment: Make sure you have shared your assets when posting a script. `Collection.loadTable: Collection asset 'users/Ctester14/all_catchments' not found.`